# Committing Play Framework tags to SVN and triggering commit hooks

Tags: svn, playframework, playframework-1.x, pre-commit-hook

I am developing a Play Framework 1.2.5 application, and have introduced a custom tag at:

```
/path/to/project/app/views/tags/myFirstTag.html
```

According to [the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/templates#tags), this is the correct place to put it, but, our SVN commit hooks stop me from committing because SVN thinks I'm committing to a tag.

I could obviously try and go down a bureaucratic black hole and try to get the SVN hooks modified so they take into account whether a parent directory is called `trunk` but I am not very hopeful, especially in a short timeframe.

Therefore, are there any other folders within the Play tree namespace that are treated in the same way as `app/views/tags`? If not, is it something that can be configured?

Comment: For the time being I've abandoned the tag and inlined the code, but it's not ideal. I could also create a Java tag and add it to the source code but an HTML tag would be a much choice if only I could commit it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked in the code and it looks like tags/ is hard coded in `GroovyTemplate.invokeTag` method:

`370: tagTemplate = (BaseTemplate)TemplateLoader.load("tags/" + templateName + "." + callerExtension);`

so no way you can change it without modifying framework code. :/